# If $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then prove that $f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c,b+c]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, proof-verification

Okay,

So, we have $a,b,c$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$.

Prove that if $f(x)$ is an integrable function in $[a,b]$ then $f(x-c)$ is integrable on $[a+c, b + c]$ with $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ = $\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We given that $f$ is integrable, so there is a number $L$ such that 
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=L$$

$$\int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c)dx\underset{u=x-c\\du=dx\\x=a+c\to u=a\\x=b+c\to u=b}{=}
\int_a^b f(u)du=\int_a^b f(x)dx=L$$

Comment: It was easier that I thought, thank you. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

R.H.S=$\int^{b+c}_{a+c} f(x-c) dx = \int^{b}_{a} f(z) dz = \int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx $=L.H.S.

I have used two things:

1. Substituted $z=x-c$. 
   So the limits are $z=b$ (upper) and $z=a$ (lower).
2. A property of definite integral used: $\int^{b}_{a} f(z) dz = \int^{b}_{a} f(x) dx$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant **Riemann-integrable**.

A rigorous theorem to justify the calculation of other answers is the theorem as follows (Theorem $6.19$ from Rudin's  *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, third edition):

> **Theorem** Suppose $\varphi$ is a strictly increasing continuous function that maps an interval $[A, B]$ onto $[a, b]$. Suppose $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a, b]$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $\beta$ and $g$ on $[A, B]$ by 
>   $$\beta(y) = \alpha(\varphi(y)), \quad g(y) = f(\varphi(y)).$$
>   Then $g \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ and
>   $$\int_A^B g d\beta = \int_a^b f d\alpha.$$

The theorem is stated in a more general *Riemann-Stieltjes* sense and is proved by constructing relevant partitions for $[A, B]$. To apply it, you can simply take $\alpha = \beta = x$ for your case. Can you find $g$ for your case?

Comment: This theorem reffers to something more general than what I asked.
I think that in my case g(x) = f(x-c).